Change Regional Format
What is command to change regional format to other region with Batch script?
If in powershell, i do this with:
$GID=111
Set-WinHomeLocation $GID



powershell -command "$GID=111; Set-WinHomeLocation $GID" is the obvious solution. Does that fit your needs?

if possible with pure batch, I prefer not calling powershell.

The local is stored in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International, item LocaleName, so you can set it with the reg command. If that's not enough, you might need to also set the items listed here.

I tried reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v LocaleName /t REG_SZ /d id-ID /f, successfully but the region format not changed
